# Can I mix Euler-Maruyama with RK45?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following SDE:

$$dy(t) = a(t)dt + b(t) dW$$

In Euler-Maruyama (EM) integration method, we substitute the Wiener process during each time step of during $dt$ with $\sqrt{dt}\mathcal N(0,1)$ and use the usual Euler method for integration. My question is as follows:

**Is it correct to do the same with other deterministic solvers such as  Runge-Kutta (RK). i.e., feed the solver with a *deterministic* gradient according to $\frac{dy}{dt} = a(t) + \frac{b(t)}{\sqrt{dt}}\mathcal N(0,1)$?**

My intuition says it is flawed since, in RK, derivatives are estimated at fractional timesteps, $dt/4, dt/2$, etc. In a real stochastic process, the Wiener process can diffuse during such fractional timesteps, but the deterministic treatment stated earlier does not.  Is my intuition correct?

Comment: In short: the actual solution is more complicated. This might be relevant/useful for you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622860/4th-order-runge-kutta-scheme-for-stochastic-differential-equations

Also, in "Introduction to Stochastic Differential Equations" by Thomas C. Gard you might find resources on how RK4 looks for (Stratonovich) SDEs.

Comment: Thanks, @FeedbackLooper. Gard's book answered my question.